# C# API call from MarketStack and print values - Error 403

Tags: c#

I would like to make a successful API call, then print the values in order to see if it works. My main goal is to analyze the data, after I can make a successful API call, and build a systematic strategy for trading.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)

```
namespace marketstacktest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
         
            var options = Options.Create(new MarketstackOptions() { ApiToken = "secretTokenHere" });
            var marketstackService = new MarketstackService(options, NullLogger<MarketstackService>.Instance);

            var appleSymbol = "AAPL";
            var fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-200);
            var toDate = DateTime.Now;

            //error at the await  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)."

            List<Marketstack.Entities.Stocks.StockBar> stock = await marketstackService.GetStockEodBars(appleSymbol, fromDate, toDate);
            
            foreach (var stock_i in stock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"close: {stock_i.Close}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your actual API token?

Comment: Yeah, just as a heads up, don't share your token if it's private. Anyway, the error message is just saying you're not allowed to connect to whatever you're trying to connect to. You need to somehow debug what you're sending via the API, when you make the call, and compare that with what it expects. You should probably check the documentation for your API library to see if you're just missing something obvious first. Also, this isn't much information for someone to go on if they want to help, so if there's any additional information you can provide about what you've already managed to debug, th

Comment: 403 is caused by IP allow listing rules, more accurately, this is why I see it happening in azure. so it can be things like you need to be on on your work VPN kinds of things are generally the problems.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly  Thank you for the response. Actually, I am using this from Github github.com/orshe4/marketstack . I went over multiple times on the documentation, but I did not find anything.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly do you have any tips in what direction should I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API manual, which is directly linked from the github, it gives information about all of the error codes. The relevant ones here are these two:

| Code | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `403` | `https_access_restricted` | HTTPS access is not supported on the current subscription plan. |
| `403` | `function_access_restricted` | The given API endpoint is not supported on the current subscription plan. |

Their class library on github is just wrapping a json REST api. Every call to the API is just an http request, returning data as json objects. The 403 error indicates that your request was accepted as a valid request, but intentionally rejected by the server for some reason. And according to the docs, the error was because your account is not allowed access to either https or to the type of request.

Their free-tier subscription only includes end-of-day data, which is what you requested, so it wouldn't make sense for that not to be allowed. So, your app is almost certainly making an https call.

I went to the examples at the very beginning of their quick start guide, and chose the end-of-day example to match your app, and clicked on the link. It worked, and gave a bunch of json records. But, the request they made was using 'http' not 'https'.

Changing the requst to 'https' elicited a 403 response with this content (formatted for readability):

```json
{
    "error":
    {
        "code": "https_access_restricted",
        "message": "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."
    }
}
```

At this point we have enough to be almost certain that this is your issue. The final thing is to go look up how to turn https requests off in their class library. To avoid having to go through the code, I checked the help at the bottom of the page one more time, and found this (formatted for readability):

```cs
    var options = Options.Create(new MarketstackOptions(){
        ApiToken = apiKey,
        MaxRequestsPerSecond = 3,
        Https = true 
    });
```

Welp. This should probably be in their first example, since that's what people are most likely to try first, but it's not. So, to stop trying to make http requests, you just need to set the `Https` option to `false` in your code. You just need to add that to the options in your code, like so:

```cs
    var options = Options.Create(new MarketstackOptions(){
        ApiToken = "secretTokenHere",
        Https = false
    });
```

I will leave the testing to you, but from the browser test, we know that the request should work, unless there's a bug in their library. Given the information that was available, this is almost certainly the issue.

Comment: So, I noticed that you said in the comments that you had gone through the documentation multiple times. The two suggestions I made in my original comment were: 1. compare what the API expects with what you're sending and 2. check the API docs to see if it's something simple.

Comment: I know sometimes it's easy to miss something, but all you had to do is search the API doc page for "403" and you would have known the library was either making an https call, or calling for data you don't have a subscription for. Seeing and testing the request was step _one_ of three in their quick start and it was just one click.

Comment: As problems go, this one was about as easy as it gets. The only thing I can figure is that when you went over the docs "multiple times" you weren't focusing on what 403 meant. Focusing on finding information on that answered the question for me in a few minutes of my time. I tested the link to see what the 403 looked like, but that actually wasn't necessary. Just immediately going back to the github readme would have found the Https option in no time.

Comment: So, you asked if I had any tips. I guess my tip is just try hard to take what you have and focus on what you need to figure it out. If you restructure the way you approach a problem to take into account your knowns and unknowns, you are going to find developing software a lot less frustrating in the long run.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to go over and explain it. I tested, and everything is working well now. I really appreciate your help, and you thought me a lot like how to think and and how to find the root of the problem. You're a good person.

Comment: Hey, glad it worked for you! Thank you for the kind words. Be careful with the stock stuff, I know of at least a few folks that thought they had a great system worked out that turned out to not be as great as they thought. :) See you around!